# Windows Unattended installation - run script as specific user

Tags: installation, unattended-processing, unattend-file

I am developing Windows installation on a local computer with unattended answer file and use setup.exe.
In the unattended.xml I am adding a user X with a password.
I want to add a script to the installation. The script does cipher to my files in a specific folder c:\cipherfiles, and I want to run that command **under user X** (that user X will have the certificate for this folder).

running it using SetupComplete.cmd, LogonCommands\AsynchronousCommand, Microsoft-Windows-Setup\RunAsynchronousCommand or RunSynchronousCommand didn't work.

any idea how should I do it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ain't a job for "RUNAS" ?

```
runas /user:$username <program>
```

or

```
runas /user:$username@$domain <program>
```

I think including this on your SetupComplete.cmd would be enough.